# Is Spyder the only Python IDE with a proper variable explorer?

Tags: python, ide, spyder

Are there any other IDEs for Python, which have such a MATLAB-like variable explorer?

I'm working on a lot of data and sometimes it gets cumbersome to check dimensions, shapes, and types in debug mode. Is Spyder really the only way of dealing with data?
Juypter notebook is nice, however it still requires you to explicitly run `variable.shape` or `len(variable)` in a new cell.

Comment: I think the feature you want is called REPL

Comment: You may like Jupyter Lab, which allows you to attach a console to your notebook -- this means you don't have to create a new cell in the notebook. You'll still have to type stuff, but at least your notebook won't become messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio community edition is also good for Python. It is available for Mac too.  It has variable explorer. https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community

Comment: Upvoted because it's a useful answer, but I'm on Ubuntu for machine learning purposes.

Comment: I too use VSCode for ML on ubuntu and os x.